# What is/was the purpose of std::make_array? Is it still needed in C++20?

Tags: c++, templates, std

I just found that in library fundamentals TS v2 there is a [`make_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array) (`std::experimental::make_array`) template that allows to deduce an arrays type from its parameters. I guess the main intention was to enable usage of `auto` similar to the example on cppreference:

```
auto x = std::experimental::make_array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Is there a different motivation that I don't see?

With the new type deduction facilites in C++20, can one still expect that `make_array` will make it into the standard one day, or is it already obsolete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`make_array(1,'2',3,4,5)` or `make_array<float>(1,'2',3,4,5)` would be valid whereas [Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) of [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides) only allows same type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: But you could do `std::array name = {1.f, 2.f};`, specifying neither the type nor the size.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: That's class template argument deduction. There's a [specific deduction guide for it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides).